# is there any way i can include space of specific word both at front and end using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to format one word in a  string and want to add space both at front and end if its not present .Is there any way to achieve the same.

Code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "";
        String in = "Hi UimIMAGE [rofl]test IMAGE [rofl] notify the bull";

         test = in.replaceAll("IMAGE \\[(.*?)\\]", "$1");
         //String.format("%1$" + (1) + "s", str);
        System.out.println(test);
    }


}
```

As of now If i run this I see it just return me .
Hi Uimrofltest rofl notify the bull
I instead wanted a regex which will add space before and after my given regex if the space not there .Is there anything I can do without manuplulating the string manually .
**Expected output** 
Hi Uim rofl test rofl notify the bull

Comment: why do you need to use regex for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `String#replaceAll` here:

```
String in = "Hi UimIMAGE [rofl]test IMAGE [rofl] notify the bull";
String out = in.replaceAll("\\s*IMAGE \\[(.*?)\\]\\s*", " $1 ");
System.out.println(in);
System.out.println(out);
```

This prints:

```
Hi UimIMAGE [rofl]test IMAGE [rofl] notify the bull
Hi Uim rofl test rofl notify the bull
```

The idea behind the regex is to capture `IMAGE [something]` tags, and then replace with just the contents in square brackets.  Note that we also capture any optional whitespace on either ends, and then pad the replacement with just a single space on both ends, to avoid unwanted extra whitespace.

Comment: I donot want to remove space .If it's not there just want to add it .if its there I just want to take the text inside bracket

Comment: Please provide more examples in your question which convey exactly the behavior you want.